# Some applications' GUI is zoomed in and I can't make it normal size. How can I fix that?

Tags: gui, display-resolution

TeamViewer example:
[image]

Same with GNU Octave, but if I start GNU Octave with `sudo` it works normally and GUI is scaled as it should be. I have the problem only with several applications, others don't have this issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are the **Titlebar Buttons** / **Maximize** and **Minimize** enabled in `gnome-tweaks` **Window Titlebars**?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes, they are enabled